# run script in Dockerfile

Tags: docker, dockerfile

I have to run my .sh script in Dockerfile based on "grafana/grafana" but I'm not sure how to do it.

```
FROM grafana/grafana
COPY setup.sh /setup.sh
CMD ["/bin/bash", "/setup.sh"]
```

after `docker run` my script is not running. I guess it due to in [grafana Dockerfile](https://github.com/grafana/grafana-docker/blob/master/Dockerfile) runs another sh script.

Comment: Can you share your setup.sh file too?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Can you please try if that works:

```
RUN ./setup.sh
```

Answer (score 1):

There are two ways to do it inside Dockerfile

`RUN <command>` (shell form, the command is run in a shell, which by default is /bin/sh -c on Linux or cmd /S /C on Windows)

`RUN ["executable", "param1", "param2"]` (exec form)